# Scan if the folder has .zip files then delete it-RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, file-io, zip

i have a functionality where all the uploaded files are first saved to a public/submitted_folder.Now the enhancement to it this functionality is that the user can view all the uploaded files in zip.i have implemented the functionality that allows user to download the files in zip format.now i have a problem here.i need to delete the newly generated zip file after its downloaded.I want to scan the submitted_folder to scan if any zip files exists and then delete it.how can i do that.what if there are more subfolders such as submitted_folder/folder1/folder2,how  can i scan all of them to find and delete any zip files.i referred [api for File in ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html),but confused...

Comment: try searching for deleting files in ruby and traversing a directory in ruby. that should get you started.

Comment: i tried but unfortunately i didn't got a reliable one..i tried File.fnmatch and even went through api at [http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-fnmatch]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with files, try sticking with the `Dir` and `File` methods. There are great tutorials out there to get you started, I'd suggest [this screencast](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/ruby-for-newbies-working-with-directories-and-files/).

### Regarding your question

When you are in the right directory, grabbing and deleting zip files is easy.

**Grab all zip-files**

```
files = Dir.glob("*.zip")
```

**Deleting a certain file:**

```
File.delete("#{file}")
```

**Extracting the files** is a bit more tricky, I myself created a folder to put all the extracted files into and then worked from there. You will also need the `rubyzip` gem to handle the ZIP files better.

```
require 'zip/zip'
# creates a directory with a name
Dir.mkdir("#{Dir.pwd}/#{name}") unless File.exists?("#{Dir.pwd}/#{name}")

# opens up the zip file
zipfile = Zip::ZipFile::open(Dir.pwd + "/" + zip_path)

# changes the working directory to the newly created folder
Dir.chdir "#{name}"

# unzips the zip and returns the xml files in it

files = []
zipfile.each do |file|
    zipfile.extract(file, "#{Dir.pwd}/#{file.name}") unless File.exists?("#{Dir.pwd}/#{file.name}")
end
```

## Edit

As it turns out, there's a simple function to get search the current directory and all the subdirectories. `**` being the key

```
all_zip_files = Dir.glob("**/*.zip")
```

After you grabbed those files, you can extract, delete or do whatever you wish :)

Comment: thanks TheChamp..i will appreciate if you post the code for building the loop as well

Comment: I just added the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using linux, you can execute bash commands from ruby.

Below is the linux command that removes all the files with extension .zip under the path "path"(including sub directories)

```
find path -type f -name *.zip -delete
```

execute it from app using

```
system("find path -type f -name *.zip -delete")
```

or

```
`find path -type f -name *.zip -delete`
```

Comment: Thanks *vimsha*,but i need little more dynamic approach.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by dynamic approach?

Comment: I'm not sure about the levels of the nested folders that would be generate hence i know the start point and not the end point where the search ends.

Comment: All you need to know is the start point to use `find`. It finds the file with the "zip" recursively in all subfolders under the follder given as "path"